# Gatsby - Unable to set environment variables

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby

In my `gatsby-config.js` I've used the `dotenv` package to set env vars

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.DEPLOY_ENV}`,
});
```

and then in my `package.json` a script to deploy to different environments

```
"deploy:staging": "DEPLOY_ENV=staging gatsby build --prefix-paths && s3-deploy ..."
```

In my `src/html.js`, I have an asset that I want to include

```
<script src={`//${process.env.ASSET_HOST}/app.js`}></script>
```

When I log the `DEPLOY_ENV` from `gatsby-config.js` it is set to `staging`, however, when I log `process.env` in `src/html.js`, `ASSET_HOST` is set as the one in my `.env.production` file, so when I deploy to staging it uses assets from my production host.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I think `DEPLOY_ENV` (as `NODE_ENV`) is a reserved environment variable. That's why `DEPLOY_ENV=staging` is not working in your case.

The [Gatsby docs on environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#additional-environments-staging-test-etc) advices to use a secondary environment variable for additionnal environement support.

You can add a `.env.staging` file in your root folder, where you put your `ASSET_HOST` env var.

Then run gatsby with `ACTIVE_ENV=staging gatsby develop`

Comment: what makes you think that it's a reserved word? in addition the OP asked how to run gatsby build and not develop

Comment: @Dejell you are probably right for the reserved word. My answer was made one year ago and I honnestly can't remember why I said that today. However, the documentation I linked has been detailed a lot, have you read it? (the complete page)